# How to get and use packets coming to a tunnel interface?

Tags: networking, network-interface, vpn, tunneling

I have created a tunnel interface in Linux and assigned an IP for its local and remote addresses. Then, I have created a route for that interface. I want to get the packets coming to that interface and use them somewhere else. For example, send the packets to some host with a TCP/UDP socket. I try to do this for research purposes and for learning sake. I may be doing completely irrelevant, please correct me.

Here are the commands I've run.

```
sudo ip tunnel add mytun mode ipip local 10.2.1.1 remote 10.2.1.1
sudo ip link set mytun up
sudo ip route add 10.2.0.0/16 dev mytun
```

I want to send a packet to `10.2.1.2` and capture that packet in the tunnel interface.

Obviously, I'm missing something conceptually and perhaps mixing things up. I've heard that some VPN clients implement something similar, create a tunnel interface and route traffic in that interface in a UDP channel to the VPN gateway. I wanted to explore how things work and experiment with it.

Edit:

Here is the output from a computer that works as I described. Computer is connected to a VPN client.

```
% ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:66:5a:01:9c:72 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 88:66:5a:01:9c:72 
    inet6 fe80::4e3:d805:211e:482c%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.1.27 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 0a:66:5a:01:9c:72 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether d2:41:09:96:68:02 
    inet6 fe80::d041:9ff:fe96:6802%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether d2:41:09:96:68:02 
    inet6 fe80::d041:9ff:fe96:6802%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:bc:33:c0:a0:01 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:bc:33:c0:a0:00 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:bc:33:c0:a0:05 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:bc:33:c0:a0:04 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:bc:33:c0:a0:01 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 13 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::8a35:50aa:7ece:babb%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::1fca:c7f5:9c76:6e18%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1400
    inet 10.212.232.54 --> 10.212.232.54 netmask 0xffffffff 

% netstat -r -n
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           en0       
10/24              10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.1/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.2/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.3/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.4/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.5/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.6/24          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.10/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.20/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.30/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.31/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.33/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.50/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.70/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.80/23         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.0.100/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.1.10/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.1.20/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.1.50/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.1.200/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.2.10/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.2.20/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.2.50/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.2.80/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.2.81/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.10/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.20/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.30/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.35/29        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.36/22        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.40/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.41/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.42/23        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.42.7         10.212.232.54      UGHS         utun2       
10.10.42.8         10.212.232.54      UGHS         utun2       
10.10.44/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.45/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.46/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.47/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.48/21        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.56/22        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.60/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.61/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.62/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.65/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.70/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.80/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.81/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.82/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.87/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.90/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.93/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.95/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.112/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.120/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.150/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.151/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.180/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.182/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.184/22       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.200/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.212/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.10.220/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.20/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.20.40.128/25    10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.30.30/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32/24           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.1/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.2/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.3/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.4/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.5/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.6/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.16/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.16.252/30    10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.34/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.36/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.199/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.249/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.250/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.251/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.252/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.253/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.32.254/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.34/24           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.34.1/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.34.21/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.36/24           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.36.1/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.40/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.41/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.43/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.45/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.46/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.47/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.49/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.51/24           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.51.1/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.52/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.53/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.54/15           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.56/15           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.58/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.59/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.60/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.61/16           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.66/24           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.66.1/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.66.2/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.66.3/24         10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.66.12/22        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.75/23           10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100/22          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100.4/22        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100.7/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100.8/24        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100.11/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.100.12/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.101.64/18       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.104.100/23      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.110/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.123/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.130/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.130.200/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.140/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.145/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.8/22        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.24/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.25/26       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.26/27       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.28/22       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.32/22       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.146.254/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147/21          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.16/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.32/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.48/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.64/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.80/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.96/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.112/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.128/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.144/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.160/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.176/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.192/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.200/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.208/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.216/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.224/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.232/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.240/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.147.248/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.178.229.31      10.212.232.54      UGHS         utun2       
10.201/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.202/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.203/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.204/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.212.232.54/32   127.0.0.1          UGSc           lo0       
10.226/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250/21          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250/16          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.8/21        10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.16/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.24/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.32/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.40/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.48/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.56/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.64/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.72/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.80/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.88/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.96/21       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.104/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.112/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.120/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.122/25      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.122.128/27  10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.124/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.125/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.126/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.127/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.128/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.129/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.130/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.131/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.132/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.133/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.134/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.136/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.137/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.138/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.139/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.146/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.147/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.148/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.149/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.150/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.200/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.208/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
10.250.216/21      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#6             UCS            en0      !
172.16.20/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.22/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.30/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.40/22       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.44/24       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.135/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.136/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.137/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.138/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.139/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.16.140/24      10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.17/21          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
172.18             10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
192.168.0/16       10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
192.168.1          link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.1        50:68:a:63:26:e8   UHLS           en0       
192.168.1.1/32     link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.1.1        50:68:a:63:26:e8   UHLWIir        en0   1194
192.168.1.27/32    link#6             UCS            en0      !
192.168.2          10.212.232.54      UGSc         utun2       
224.0.0/4          link#6             UmCS           en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en0       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI         en0       
255.255.255.255/32 link#6             UCS            en0      !
```

Note that public IPs redacted and it's from a macOS system. I can ping IPs in 10.250.0.0/16 range.

Comment: Can you give your current system network settings (in order to make answer with an adapted example)? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route`.

Comment: Likely you would not success with tunneling to the same host or this can be very and very difficult. Better try another end of the tunnel on virtual machine.

Comment: I'm sorry there are too many not needed piece of information. I'd rather not give any answer (I would not have expected OP gives any real public IP addresses either)

Comment: Here's a simple link instead: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/tunneling#ipip_tunnels

Comment: Please see my edited question. I think it has something to do with the `10.212.232.54/32   127.0.0.1          UGSc           lo0` route.